# c# How to pass a variable from method into main?

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning c#, I am creating a program that asks for user's first name, if the first letter is not capitalised the program will automatically capitalise it, I wanted to put this into a method but am having trouble with returning the value from the method into the Main method.

Here is the code I am trying

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        //Method for letter capitalisation 
        static string capitalise(string userName, char letter) { //users name, letter being replaced
            letter = char.ToUpper(letter); //capitalise first letter
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(userName);
            sb1.Remove(0, 1); //removes first letter
            sb1.Insert(0, letter); //inserts first letter from letter object
            userName = sb1.ToString(); //writes string builder into string
            return userName; //returns method value to the object
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstName;
            string lastName;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your First Name?");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your Last Name?");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            char capitalFirst = firstName[0]; // writes first letter of the name as a char
            if (char.IsLower(capitalFirst)) { //checks if char is lowercase 
                capitalise(firstName, capitalFirst); //calls for method and writes parameters
                firstName = capitalise(userName); // <--- here i am trying to write the user first name as a result from the capitalise method

            }

            //Same for last name...

            Console.WriteLine(firstName + " " + lastName);
```

}

The Error: The name username does not exist in the current context

Comment: Leaving aside the name scoping problem, there are a number of bad programming practices here that you should break while you are still a beginner. Name methods to follow naming practices: Methods are capitalized, so it should be `Capitalize`, not `capitalize`. Do not change the value of a parameter needlessly; local variables are cheap. say `char capitalized = letter.ToUpper();` rather than make `letter` mean two things; it will be easier to understand and debug your program if you follow this convention.

Comment: Pass only the information you need; do you need to pass both the string and the first letter? No; that's redundant. The first letter can be computed from the string, so just pass the string.

Comment: And finally, though I understand this is an exercise for a beginner, in real world code like this **you should know that almost nothing you believe about names is true**. It is not true that everyone has a first and last name; Teller of Penn&Teller legally is just "Teller". It is not true that the first letter of the last name is always capitalized; what is the last name of `Ludwig van Beethoven`? If it is `van Beethoven` then it is not capitalized; if it is `Beethoven` then where in your scheme do you type in the `van`?

Comment: See https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ for many more falsehoods you might believe about names.

Comment: @EricLippert Ironic that i didn't capitalise 'capitalise' haha, thank you for your tips, yes I just picked up C# and I wanted to practice string manipulation and using OOP methods, but I will definitely take into consideration all the tips given here, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really overthinking this.

As the other answers and comments mentioned, yours is a problem of *variable scope*. In this case, "scope" refers to the block of code where a variable is declared and is therefore accessible.

Any variable declared inside of a brace pair (`{`, `}`) is only accessible inside of that pair. This area is referred to as a **block**. Method parameters - like `username` and `letter` in your example, are only accessible within the body of the method, conveniently also delimited by braces.

For instance, this is valid:

```
{
  string s;
  s = "blah;
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

while this is not

```
{
    string s;
    s = "blah"
}
Console.WriteLine(s); // s has gone out of scope and does not exist here.
```

In your sample, there are a number of issues. You're calling `capitalise` in two different ways, one of which - with only one parameter, while the method expects two - is invalid. 
But, the immediate problem is this:

```
firstName = capitalise(userName);
```

`userName` is invalid here because it is an argument of `capitalize`. `Main` knows nothing of that `userName`, because it is declared in a different *scope*.

You *might* have meant:

```
firstName = capitalise(firstName, capitalFirst);
```

Complete working sample below. Use of `StringBuilder` is overkill and unnecessary in this case. `StringBuilder` is typically used when you need to build very large strings by concatenating a bunch of stuff. String concatenation requires some allocation and copying and potentially triggers the garbage collector, which can be a significant performance hit, and can consume tons of memory in extreme circumstances.

Good luck!

```
using System;

public class Program
{

    public static string Capitalize(string s)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return string.Empty;

        string result = char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
            string firstName;
            string lastName;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your First Name?");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your Last Name?");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            firstName = Capitalize(firstName);
            lastName = Capitalize(lastName);
            Console.Write("Hello, {0} {1}.", firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @3Dave thank you for your solution, I now understand how to correctly pass those arguments(parameters?) into the method. Thank you for the help. Could you please explain this line for me as im not 100% sure what exactly its doing.
` string result = char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);` Cheers

Comment: @EKrol sure. `s[0]` refers to the first character in the string `s`. `char` is a class. `char.ToUpper(s[0])` returns that character, converted to upper case (if it was already upper case, it just returns the character.) `s.Substring(1)` returns a new string made by copying every character in `s` starting with index `1`, which is the *second* character in the string. (All arrays and strings start with index `0`, so `0` is the first item, `1` is second, and so on`.) `.Substring(1)` just gives you a string that doesn't have the first character.

Comment: I see, cheers, and what is result? Is it a default object which is the result from the variable being passed into the method(firstName, lastName etc)? Or is it just something you have created within the method?

Comment: @EKrol `result` is a new local string variable that contains the capitalized version of the name. It is `return`ed to `Main`, where it is then assigned to one of `Main`'s variables. When you say `firstName = Capitalize(firstName);`, it runs `Capitalize` and whatever is `return`ed from that function is assigned to `firstName`. If I said `lastName = Capitalize("foo");`, then lastName would contain "Foo" after that line of code.

Comment: @EKrol I strongly recommend stepping through the code in the debugger so that you can see how control passes around, when variable values change, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you may be being confused by some basic programming semantics, so I'll try to break this down for you.

- For one, you don't "pass" values from methods to the `Main` function of a program. You *return* values (hence the return statement)

  You *pass* parameters to methods and functions (for example: `Test(1,2,3);`, I've passed the `int`s 1, 2 and 3 to the method `Test`). I bring this up because I believe that you may be under the impression that you are modifying the scope/variables in `Main` by calling `capitalise`, which is not (and should not) be the case.
- Second, you need to understand **scope**, variables only exist in the scope within which they are declared; scope is more complex than this, but simply put, you can think of anything within curly brances ({ these }) as being a new scope; the only things that exist in that new scope are the things that exist above that scope and inside of it.

  Your `Main` method and the `capitalise` method have two different scopes, you cannot use `userName` in the `Main` method because `userName` only exists in `capitalise`.

So, the solution would be to update your `Main` method like so:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstName;
            string lastName;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your First Name?");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your Last Name?");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            char capitalFirst = firstName[0]; // writes first letter of the name as a char
            char capitalLast = lastName[0];
            if (char.IsLower(capitalFirst) || char.IsLower(capitalLast)) { //checks if char is lowercase 
                firstName = capitalise(firstName, capitalFirst);
                lastName = capitalise(lastName, capitalLast); 

            }

            //Same for last name...

            Console.WriteLine(firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace capitalize function for ToTitleCase:

```
        TextInfo textInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

        string resultStr = textInfo.ToTitleCase("firstname secondname");
```

Result of resultStr variable is = "Firstname Secondname"

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have any variable with name "userName" in Main.  You need take return of capitalise and then put in some variable. For example:

```
string userName = capitalise(firstName, capitalFirst); //calls for method and writes parameters
firstName = capitalise(userName); // <--- here i am trying to write the user first name as a result from the capitalise method
```